# Re-set the Share value for each group in the main report

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a main report with two grouping (Group 1:Event Class and Group 2:Event ID). In my main report I have a sub report which pass out a share value. 
In the sub report, there is only one grouping, Event ID. 
The code I written to pass the value to the main report as shown below.

**Code in Sub report:**
WhilePrintingRecords; 
Shared CurrencyVar HireEqAmt := HireEqAmt+{@Amt}

**Code in Main report:**
WhilePrintingRecords; 
Shared CurrencyVar HireEqAmt; 
HireEqAmt

My detail information is all in Group 2.
I will like to have a reset function for each group 1 footer. 
And at the Report Footer, I will have a grand total.

How can I do that?
Currently the value does not reset at each group 1 level.

Thanks.

Regards,
Mavis

Answer (score 0):

Resetting means not mentioning the variable instead you need to assign a default value like `0`

For E.g:

```
WhilePrintingRecords; 
Shared CurrencyVar HireEqAmt; 
HireEqAmt:=0
```